# $T^3=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*) \rightarrow$ T is self adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be a normal transformation on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space; that is, $TT^*=T^*T$, where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Prove that if $T^3=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)$, then $T$ is self adjoint.

I have tried to do some math on $(Tv,u)$ but I was not successful in proving the following: $(Tu,v)=(u,Tv)$ which is what I need for self-adjoint transformation.

**Edit:**
$(T^3,v)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(T+T^*\right),u \right)= \left( Tu,v\right)+  \left( T^*u,v\right)=\left( u,T^*v\right)+\left( u,Tv\right)=\left( u,T^3v\right)$
Therefore, $T^3$ is self adjoint. Does it mean that $T$ is self adjoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show that $T^3$ self-adjoint?

Comment: I have managed to prove that, yes.

Comment: Are you dealing with finite-dimensional spaces, or with infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces?

Comment: A finite space, see my edit.

Comment: That $T^3$ is self-adjoint doesn't automatically imply that $T$ is self-adjoint. But here, the equation $T^3 = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(T + T^{\ast}\bigr)$ gives more information. Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. What does the equation tell you about $\lambda$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you implying I should go with the direction of proving all the eigenvalues are real, therefore $T$ will be adjoint?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is my solution here correct? Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. Therefore $Tv=\lambda v \rightarrow T^3v=\lambda^3 v$. We multiply to original equation from the right and get $\lambda^4v=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda + \lambda^*) \lambda$. We get $2\lambda^4=|\lambda|^2+\lambda^2$ where $\lambda^*$ is a complex number. hence the eigenvalue is real and T is self adjoint.

Comment: $T^*v=\lambda^*v$? isn't it right?

Comment: My doubt is that I assume from the start that $\lambda$ is real but no one told me it's the case.

Comment: I don't see how you get $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ from $2\lambda^4 = \lvert\lambda\rvert^2 + \lambda^2$. You'd need to fill that in. I wouldn't have multiplied with $\lambda$, without that you get $\lambda^3 = \operatorname{Re} \lambda$ - which gives you quite a bit more than just $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, by the way.

Comment: If $Tv = \lambda v$, then $T^{\ast} v = \overline{\lambda} v$, if $T$ is normal. Do you denote the complex conjugate with $\lambda^{\ast}$ rather than $\overline{\lambda}$?

Comment: I do mean $\overline \lambda$.

Comment: To get $\overline{\lambda}$, you can write "\overline{\lambda}".

Comment: Anyway, I think I got it. $\lambda^3 =  Re \space  \lambda$, therefore the eigenvalue is real, and $T$ is self adjoint?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda^3 = \operatorname{Re} \lambda$ gives you $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1\}$, so all eigenvalues of $T$ are real. But you still need to say why $\lambda^3 = \operatorname{Re}\lambda$ implies that $\lambda$ is real.

Comment: Yes, it really does simply come down to showing that $\lambda^3 = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda+\overline\lambda)$ implies $\lambda \in \{0, \pm 1\}$ as Daniel Fischer said. I did this by observing that $\lambda^3 \in \mathbb R$ and writing $\lambda = \omega r$ with $\omega^3=1$ and $r \in \mathbb R$. Using the possible values for $\omega+\overline\omega$, I eventually got $r \in \{0, \pm 1\}$, which gives $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda^6=1$. In the latter case, $\overline\lambda=\lambda^{-1}$, the first equation becomes a polynomial equation. A lot of steps, but doable. I wonder if there's an easier way.

Comment: I also wonder if there's an easier way of doing it. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: that $T$ is normal helps : apply the spectral theorem to get $T = P DP^*$ with $PP^* = I$ and $D$ is diagonal

Comment: Yes, the spectral theorem is the reason why it's enough to show that $T$ has only real eigenvalues.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein If $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ and $z^3\in \mathbb{R}$, then we have $\operatorname{Re} z > 0 \iff z^3 < 0$, and analogously for $z^3 > 0$. So $z^3$ has the opposite sign of $\operatorname{Re} z$. Thus $\lambda^3 = \operatorname{Re} \lambda \implies \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. And then $\lambda^3 = \lambda$ is easily solved.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is easier. :)

Comment: I managed to prove that $T^*T=TT^*$ from $T^3=(T+T^*)/2$, so no need to assume normality.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** true that if $T$ is normal and $T^3$ is selfadjoint, then $T$ is selfadjoint. Example:
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\pi/3}&0\\0&e^{i\pi/3}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $T^3=I$ (or, even when $n=1$ and $T=e^{i\pi/3}$).

But here we know more. Since $T$ is normal, it is unitarily diagonalizable. So we may assume that $T$ is diagonal. We can then see that the equality $T^3=\text{Re}\,T$ will be satisfied by the eigenvalues of $T$. If 
$$\tag1
\lambda^3=\text{Re}\,\lambda
$$
and we write $\lambda=re^{it}$, we immediately get 
$$\tag2
r^3e^{3it}=r\cos t.
$$
There is the obvious solution $r=0$, i.e. $\lambda=0$. For $r\ne0$, the equality $(2)$ becomes
$$\tag3
r^2\cos 3t=\cos t$$ and $$\tag4 r^2\sin 3t=0.
$$
The equality $(4)$ gives us $t=k\pi/3$. And now we have 
$$\tag5
r^2=\frac{\cos k\pi/3}{\cos k\pi}=(-1)^k\cos k\pi/3.
$$For $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$, the right-hand-side in $(5)$ is 
$$
0,-\frac12,-\frac12,1,-\frac12,-\frac12.
$$
As $r^2>0$, the only acceptable values of $k$ are $0$ and $3$, which give $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=-1$ respectively.

In summary, the only possible eigenvalues of $T$ are $0,1,-1$, and thus $T$ (being normal) is selfadjoint.

Answer (score 0):

$T^3=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)\Rightarrow T^4=\frac{1}{2}(T^2+TT^*)=\frac{1}{2}(T^2+T^*T)\text{ implies }TT^*=TT^*.$
Hence T is normal. Since $T$ is normal, there exists an orthonormal basis consists of its eigenvectors such that $T=UDU^*$, where $D$ is diagonal and $U$'s column vectors are $T$'s eigenvectors. $T$ is normal also implies $U^*(T^3)U=\frac{1}{2}(U^*TU+U^*T^*U)$ is a real diagonal matrix.
Let $\lambda=a+bi$ be one of the $T$'s eigenvalue, then $\lambda^3=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda+\bar{\lambda})\Rightarrow a^3-3ab^2+(3a^2b-b^3)i=a.$ Suppose $b\neq 0,$ then $b^2=3a^2\neq 0\Rightarrow 1=a^2-9a^2=-8a^2\Rightarrow a=\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}i,$ leads to a contradiction. Hence $b=0$, i.e. $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, which means $T=T^*.$